# How to check logs in this case ( One log file for all the dates )

Tags: log4j, logging

How to check logs in this case .

Actually from our Application , we are contacting some third party Service (Application )
The way they provided their log file is different . (Only one log file no matter what the date is )

For instance , this looks this way

```
11:29:32,862 -  INFO  main:http-8082-2 <ServicePlugger> <gurthu>DE</gurthu>
11:29:32,862 -  INFO  main:http-8082-2 <ServicePlugger> <enni>0</enni>
11:29:32,862 -  INFO  main:http-8082-2 <ServicePlugger> <konadate>0</konadate>
11:29:32,862 -  INFO  main:http-8082-2 <ServicePlugger> <costentha>0</costentha>
```

Now my question is how to check log files ??
Whether the starting lines indicate time  (11:29:32,862) ??

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Can you not use regular expression to match the string?

Comment: I was asking about the date and the time .